# Order array by distance in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova

How to order my array results by distance ASC?

I need to sort the loop according to my geographic coordinates (latitude / longitude)

See my code:

```
function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
{
    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180
    var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180
    var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180
    var theta = lon1-lon2
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist)
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
    dist = dist * 1.609344 * 1000
    return Math.round(dist)
}
function places()
{
    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM places', [], function (tx, results) {
            for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++)
            {
                var distance = calculateDistance(mylat, mylng, results.rows.item(i).lat, results.rows.item(i).lng);
            }
        }, null);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the distance of your results inside the loop and then sort:

```
for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
  results.rows[i].distance = calculateDistance(mylat, mylng, results.rows.item(i).lat, results.rows.item(i).lng);
}
results.rows.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.distance - b.distance;
})
```